# [: -eq: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, aix

```
#!/bin/bash    
export PROCNAME=test
export TABLE_ID=0

if [ ${TABLE_ID} -eq "" ]; then
        echo hello
fi
```

above throws error:

> [: -eq: unary operator expected

How to fix this with out double square brackets  `[[ ${TABLE_ID} -eq "" ]]`.

Comment: `-eq` is for numeric comparison, use `[ ${TABLE_ID} = "" ]`

Comment: can we do some thing in export ?

Comment: @anubhava You need to quote the argument to `-z` or it fails to work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test string equality with `=`.

```
#!/bin/bash    
export PROCNAME=test
export TABLE_ID=0

if [ "${TABLE_ID}" = "" ]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-z` to test if a variable is empty:

```
if [ -z "$variable" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

From `man test`:

```
-z STRING
        the length of STRING is zero
```

See an example:

```
$ r="roar"
$ [ -z "$r" ] && echo "empty" || echo "not empty"
not empty
$ r=""
$ [ -z "$r" ] && echo "empty" || echo "not empty"
empty
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash    
export PROCNAME=test
export TABLE_ID=0

[ -z ${TABLE_ID} ] && echo hello
```